# Check if object of arrays contains any errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to check if my validation function has returned any errors before executing an insert function. Since it's returning an object of arrays I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell if my errors are empty. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious here but I'm stumped.

```
const formErrors = this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition) => {
  errors = careerHistoryPosition.errors

  if (!errors) {
    return false;
  }
});

if (formErrors === false) {
  console.log("Run insert function");
}
```

Comment: `const formErrors = this.state.careerHistoryPositions.some(position => position.errors)`

Comment: Did you mean *array of objects*?

Comment: [*map*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map) returns a (possibly empty) array, so *formErrors* will always resolve to true and `formErrors === false` will always be false (also because you're comparing an Array to a Boolean, so double false!). Consider using [*some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) instead.

Comment: @AndrewLi, your suggestion returns an error, `expected ;`

Comment: @bp123 Weird, it's valid ES6... sure it isn't a fault on your part?

Comment: @AndrewLi. formErrors always returns true. `positions.errors` is an array of objects. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bp123 Maybe check the length of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to check each object in careerHistoryPositions to see if it contains the property errors and that it is an array with at least one item. In that case, you should probably use Array.filter instead

```js
const careerHistoryPositions = [{}, {}, {errors: ['system error']}]

// check if it has property 'errors' and that it has length > 0
const errors = careerHistoryPositions.filter((pos) => pos.hasOwnProperty('errors') && pos.errors.length > 0);

// if at least one error is found
if (errors.length > 0) {
  console.log("Run insert function");
}
```